# android network calls not working in release build

Tags: android, network-programming

I'm finally ready to deploy the first release of my application but upon testing I can't perform any tasks that require network access.
It all works just fine in debug mode and as far as I can tell the request gets sent to the correct URL but the response is always empty (message: null status:0).

The project uses gradle and proguard so I have added this to it:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

At that point the system was warning me of some unfound class references so I added these lines to the proguard_rules.pro file:

```
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.**
-dontwarn com.malinskiy.superrecyclerview.**
-dontwarn com.octo.android.robospice.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.**
-dontwarn io.realm.processor.**
-dontwarn org.joda.time.**
-dontwarn org.springframework.http.**

-keep class com.fasterxml.** { *; }
-keep class com.malinskiy.superrecyclerview.** { *; }
-keep class com.octo.android.robospice.** { *; }
-keep class com.squareup.** { *; }
-keep class io.realm.processor.** { *; }
-keep class org.joda.time.** { *; }
-keep class org.springframework.http.** { *; }
```

The build succeeds and the app runs fine but the moment i try to do something that requires network access it fails.

The app doesn't crash though (error handling ftw) but it does mean that the network response listener has received a null response.

Any idea why this is happening?

update: it seems to be caused by the minification process (proguard). So perhaps I should start wondering why I kept getting those "class reference not found" warnings...

if I set minifyEnabled to false the application works fine.

Comment: Take a look at logcat, such things are usually can be found there.

Comment: thing is, when running a release build I don't have a logcat to look at.

Comment: Release builds can log to LogCat just as debug builds can. Beyond that, please explain what "I can't do anything" means. For example, are you crashing? If so, your stack traces will show up in LogCat.

Comment: might've been confusing but what I mean is that I can't view anything beyond those 2 views because the rest require network connectivity.
It's not crashing the application either, it just sends null-responses to the callback listener.

The android studio logcat remains empty (because it can't find a debuggable applicationi assume) so if you know how please explain how i can attach logcat to a release build.
(note: i install the release build through the command line)

Comment: updated OP would some extra info, seems like proguard is the culprit here... Not sure why though, it did give some weird "class reference not found" warnings regarding the HTTP libraries but most sources said it was pretty safe to ignore those.

Comment: exclude your model classes from obfuscate. i.e.
 `-keep class com.examples.model.** { *; }`